# How to manage data fetching for frequently created dynamic pages in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am working on a Next.js project (Prisma as ORM) that contains multiple parts where dynamic pages are created often.

Until now, I fetched the data using `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. I realized only now that these are only run at build time and my project only works in development for the moment.

I tried to change the data fetching to `useSWR` with a `fetcher`:

```
...
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

export default function View() {
    const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR('/api/survey-data', fetcher);
    const survey = data?.survey;

    if(error) return <div>Failed to load</div>;
    if(isLoading) return <Loading/>;
...
```

Passing through an api that calls a function that gets the data from the database using Prisma, which causes this error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser

I am unable to find a concrete example on what is the best practice for my use case. How can I fetch my data when Prisma can't run on the client?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stick with [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props) and use [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration), but if your data is changing that much, you could use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), as an example:

```js
// pages/posts/[slug].js

export default function Post({ post }) {
  return <div>{post.title}</div>;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: context.query.slug,
    },
  });
  if (!post) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
  return { props: { post } };
}
```

`getServerSideProps` runs on the server, so you will no longer get that Prisma error, and also, because it runs at request time, your user will get the most up-to-date data.

Comment: That is a way better solution, it solved it thank you !